# Manage user role in rails (Different attributes, permissions, etc...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, rolify

I'm looking for the best way, in ruby on rails 4.2, to create and manage users role with differente attributes and permissions.

I don't want to create one table for each users roles, i have some solution with enum or some gem like **cancan** or **rolify** but i want to know what is the best way to improve performance, respect the agreements, and write strong code and architecture.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: `cancan` is the best way to manage user role.See the implementation on this link http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?view=asciicast

Comment: U should use cancan gem(https://github.com/ryanb/cancan )

Comment: why cancan gem is better than rolify, or enum ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not *Cancancan or Rolify or enum*, but *Rolify + Cancancan* or *Enum + Cancancan*.

Authorization gems such as Cancancan or [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) (which I prefer) are used for managing what your users can do, based on their role. So Roles and Authorization aren't opposed, they normally complement each other.

Rolify + Pundit is a nice solution and will give your users the ability to have several roles.

For single-role-based authorization, then Enum is more straightforward. It's used especially (but not only) by apps having a hierarchy in their roles, like member, moderator, admin.

To get roles based on Enum under 5 minutes, first add a role column to users:

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0 #The default role will be the one set at 0 in user.rb
  end
end
```

Then, define the roles in user.rb

`enum role: { buyer: 0, seller: 1, admin: 2 }`

This will directly allow you to do something like `current_user.admin?`, without writing more code, which is quite convenient and clean.